# Angular 4 Printing Messages to the Console

Tags: angular, http, typescript

How to get some messages printed to the NodeJS Server console from my Angular App?

I have a Typescript that does some HTTP call and I want to log the HTTP end point to the server's console and I do not see anything getting printed at all, even though the API call seem to work. Here is the code snippet in my Typescript file:

```
    private fetchAllPowerPlants = "http://localhost:9000/powerPlants?onlyActive=false&page=1";
  loadData() {
    let url = this.fetchAllPowerPlants;
    console.log('******************************************');
    console.log(url);
    console.log('******************************************');
    return this.http.get(url)
      .map(this.extractData)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

This is all what I see in the console after I call the frontend!

```
chunk    {0} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 178 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {1} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 13.8 kB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 54.7 kB {4} [initial]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 2.49 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is angular in frontend or universal ?

Comment: If it's in frontend , we cannot get frontend logs at the server . You need to write the logs in your server code .

Comment: It is in the frontend and served using ng serve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that powerPlants is a REST endpoint configured in your Node.JS server app. A simple way to log your messages on the Node server would be creating another endpoint, e.g. "/log":

`let express = require("express"); 

    const app = express();
    ...
    app.get('/log/:msg', (req, res) => {
        console.log(req.params.msg);
    });`

From the Angular side you need to make an HTTP request to this endpoint passing the message to log.
 Since your Angular app is not deployed on the Node server (ng serve uses dev server running on port 4200), you'll also need to configure a proxy on the client so Angular requests made to the port 4200 would be redirected to the Node server that runs on port 9000. If you're not familiar with configuting proxies on the client, watch 3 min of my presentation starting from here: https://youtu.be/k8r76d8QzXs?t=2587

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! The powerPlants endpoint is a completely different API running on a different server! It is a backend application written using another technology!

Comment: This is not important for the suggested solution :)

Comment: I did not understand! What is not important for the suggested solution?

Comment: All I want is to see the url that is getting called when I click the button in my browser!

Comment: If powerPlants is an endpoint on another server and you can modify the code on this server, my solution works (assuming that server is written in Node.js). If you don't have access to the source code of that server, you can use another server as a proxy for logging.

Comment: What code should I modify on the other server that is serving my REST endpoint? It is just spitting out some JSON that I want to consume in my Angular 4 app which is hosted on a NodeJS. While I make a request from my browser to the REST API, I want to see the URL in the NodeJS console!

Comment: Though your answer might be correct, I could not follow what you have posted! You are saying to create a new endpoint, but where do I create it? The code snippet that you have provided - Where do I put it and how do I run it? It is not clear to me!

Comment: I can confirm that the server that is serving the REST endpoint is in fact sending the JSON body back to the caller with a HTTP 200. So there is definitely some problem with the Angular 4 app in rendering this information! What I can also confirm is that the Angular 4 App is in fact calling the correct URL to the backend server!

Comment: Have a look at my answer! I just wanted to know where I could see the output of the console.log(...). That was it!